# WPF displaying object properties from Observable Collection MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, observablecollection

I am trying to display the properties from an object which is contained in an observable list but it is just not working. 
I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Here is my XAMl

```
<Window x:Name="MainViewWindow" x:Class="WpfApplication1.View.MainView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.ViewModel"
    Title="MainView" Height="413.514" Width="607.095">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Label Content="Text:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="55,135,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label Content="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="98,135,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="61,108,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="{Binding UpdateNameCommand}"/>
    <Label Content="ActivateButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="52,82,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <CheckBox Content="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="173,87,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsChecked="{Binding ButtonActive}" />
    <Label Content="CustomerName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="55,166,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="173,166,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="lstPeople" Background="AliceBlue" Width="130" Margin="273,29,196,35" ItemsSource="{Binding CustomerList}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

My CustomerList is a property located in the MainViewModel:

```
     ObservableCollection<Customer> _CustomerList;
  ObservableCollection<Customer> CustomerList
  {
      get { return _CustomerList; }
      set
      {
          if (_CustomerList != value)
          {
              _CustomerList = value;
              PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CustomerList"));

          }
      }
  }
```

My Customer class only contains one property: Name

```
  public class Customer : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set
        {
            if (_Name != value)
            {
                _Name = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
            }
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
}
```

I have created an instance of the CustomerList in the MainViewModel constructor but i cannot see any of my customers showing up in the application:

```
 public MainViewModel()
  {
      ButtonActive = true;
      CustomerList = new ObservableCollection<Customer>() { new Customer() { Name = "NewCust33" } };
      CustomerList.Add(new Customer() { Name = "NewCust" });

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the property you're binding to is private?

You can only bind to [public properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643.aspx#binding_sources).

```
public ObservableCollection<Customer> CustomerList
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes sense, I can't believe I did not notice that.